# How to create a custom CSV file from Python dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to create a CSV file like this:

```
Features, Value
f1, 1
f2, 2
f3, 3
```

But I get this:

```
f1, f2, f3
1, 2, 3
```

The code I wrote:

```
my_dict = {'f1': 1, 'f2': 2, 'f3': 3}
with open('testcsv.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(my_dict)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Where do you think you code will get `Features` and `Value` from?

Comment: It will cause an error when I wrote them in writeheader()!

Comment: The labels of your header has to match the keys of your dict. Refer to the example in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to first transform your data according to the expected structure

```
data = [{'Features':i,'Value':my_dict[i]} for i in my_dict]
```

Once you do that you could use pandas to save it as CSV like so :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('testcsv.csv',index=None)
```

The resulting csv :

```
Features,Value
f1,1
f2,2
f3,3
```

Comment: Isnt pandas a overkill for that task? What if he doesn’t want to support c implementations..

Comment: @adirabargil It completely is overkill i do agree with you ,but it's so much more beginner friendly than the python standard csv library

Comment: As long as you encouraged one more person to use pandas, you get my upvote!

Comment: As a now old programmer, I do not feel that pandas is really beginner friendly. You can indeed use it without knowing Python and its containers because it uses different ones, but it is full of caveats where a beginner can fall. And I find here a lot of questions of users that thought it was magic (what Pandas is...) and hope that it could magically guess would they wanted. And on that last part Pandas is simply an additional language to learn...

Comment: I think he mean that only this specific case is beginner friendly...

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is a bit overkill here, and the csv module is enough. Simply you used it the wrong way:

```
with open('testcsv.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['Features', 'Value'])    # first write a header line
    for f, v in my_dict.items():
        w.writerow((f,v))                # then one row per item in the dict
```